# PinesNotify is not working with jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get [PinesNotify](http://pinesframework.org/pnotify/) to work with my small webapp, and I'm having some trouble. The notifications show up, but they are not styled at all. I'm using jQuery UI as the default dependency for Pines, instead of Bootstrap CSS/Js. Here are my dependancies in my HTML head:

```
<link href="style/jquery.pnotify.default.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pnotify.min.js"></script>
```

Here's my Javascript that is supposed to trigger the notification:

```
$.pnotify.defaults.styling = "jqueryui";
            $.pnotify({
                title: 'Ticket Submitted',
                text: 'Assistance will arrive shortly!',
                type:'success'
            });
```

The result is just [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFriz.png). Any help would be much appreciated! I *think* I've done everything correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it the way it shown in demos?:

```
$.pnotify({
    title: 'Ticket Submitted',
    text: 'Assistance will arrive shortly!',
    type: 'success',
    styling: 'jqueryui'
});
```

Also make sure that you have the latest version (1.2) of Notifier.